# How to designate a spot on the surface of a 3D Sphere?

Tags: graphics3d

I am trying to designate a small spot on a 3D textured globe. The
obvious way is to include a Point in the Graphics3D:

```
Graphics3D[{
    EarthGlobe,
    {Red, PointSize[.02], Point[pointOnSurfaceCartesian]},
    {Cyan, PointSize[.02], Point[subsolar]}
}, options ...]
```

[The [code for the globe](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/LocateAPointOnTheEarthsSurface/) can be found at the Demonstration Site.]

Unfortunately, this approach has aesthetic problems in certain orientations where 1) the spherical Points appear as crescents:

[image]

or 2) where the spherical Points bulge outward from the surface:

[image]

I suspect that there is an easy and efficient way to do this, but I haven't been able to find it.  I have tried the following:

- PerimetricPlot3D with RegionFunction
- PerimetricPlot3D with the parameters in a region
- SphericalPlot3D

The fastest of these is the first, but it requires 300 PlotPoints to
look reasonable for ImageSize->Medium, which is still slower than I
would like. Moreover, zooming the image leads to an ugly rendering:

[image]

Here is the code I ended up using:

```
Point3D[spot_, color_:Red, size_:.04] :=
  First@ParametricPlot3D[
    {Sin[t]Cos[p]], Sin[t]]Sin[p], Cos[t]},
    {t, 0, Pi},
    {p, 0, 2Pi},
    RegionFunction->
      Function[{x, y, z, u, v},
      EuclideanDistance[{x, y, z}, spot] <= size],
    PlotStyle->color,
    PlotPoints->300,
    Mesh->False
  ];
```

Can anyone suggest a better way?

(I am running Mathematica 11.0 on a MacBook with OSX 10.9.)

Comment: Use `Sphere` instead of `Point`?

Comment: Possibly useful? [Multiple plots in SphericalPlot3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/172068/34893).

Comment: Thank you for your answers--I learned from both of them. I accepted Carl's because 1) it was a little faster; 2) on my display, the zoom behavior was a little cleaner; and 3) the approach he took was closer to what I was doing in the rest of the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possibility is to use a [`Polygon`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Polygon) instead of a point. For example, here is a function that creates a "circular" polygon:

```
diskPolygon[lat_, long_] := Rotate[
    Polygon @ PadRight[CirclePoints[.03, 20], {20, 3}, 1],
    {
        {0,0,1},
        {Cos[long]Sin[lat],Sin[long]Sin[lat],Cos[lat]}
    }
]
```

Simple example:

```
Graphics3D[{Sphere[], Red, diskPolygon[90 Degree, -45 Degree]}]
```

[image]

We can create a [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate) allowing you to move the "disk" around the globe (I adopted the globe code from @Michael's answer):

```
earthmap = Import["https://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/57000/57752/land_shallow_topo_2048.tif"];
globe = ParametricPlot3D[
    {Sin[θ] Cos[ϕ],Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ],Cos[θ]},
    {θ,0,π},
    {ϕ,0,2 π},
    PlotStyle->Texture[earthmap],
    TextureCoordinateFunction->({#5+.5,1-#4}&),
    Mesh->True,
    SphericalRegion->True
];

Manipulate[
    Show[globe, Graphics3D @ {Red,diskPolygon[x,y]}],
    {x,0,π},
    {y,0,2 π}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could always add the point to the bitmap image directly:

```
earthmap = Import["https://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/57000/57752/land_shallow_topo_2048.tif"]
pointimage[color_, lat_] := 
  Rasterize[Graphics[{color, Disk[{0, 0}, 0.01 {1/Cos[lat], 1}]}], 
   ImageSize -> 0.01 ImageDimensions[earthmap][[1]]/Cos[lat],  
   Background -> None];
earthmappt[lat_, long_] := 
 ImageCompose[earthmap, pointimage[Red, lat], 
  Scaled[N[{long/(2 \[Pi]) + 1/2, 1/2 + lat/\[Pi]}]]]
globept[lat_, long_] := ParametricPlot3D[
  {Sin[\[Theta]] Cos[\[Phi]], Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]], 
   Cos[\[Theta]]},
  {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]},
  {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]},

  PlotStyle -> Texture[earthmappt[lat, long]],
  TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#5 + .5, 1 - #4} &),
  Mesh -> True,
  SphericalRegion -> True
  ]

globept[50 Degree, -97 Degree]
```

[image]

Adjust the `0.01` in the expression for the `ImageSize` option in `pointimage` to change the size of the point.

This will of course pixelate when zoomed in, but no more than the underlying bitmap texture does:

[image]